# Importar JSON a Excel usando VBA

Tags: json, excel, vba

Quería pediros ayuda.
He descargado de esta web http://excelerator.solutions/download/912/ el fichero JSON-to-Excel-Example-File.xlsm

Estaba readaptando a mis necesidades y al ejecutar ***JsonToExcelAdvancedExample*** da error '1004' en tiempo de ejecución se para y me lleva a ***ws.Cells(i, 2) = item("IdOrigenMetadatoPrioridades")***

No me deja extraer:

- Datos numéricos, supongo que se debe a []
- Campos con más de un dato, ya sea de texto o numérico.

¿Podría cargarse el Json de otra forma? cuando es muy largo no puedo pegarlo en la celda A1 entero, se queda a medias.

Mil gracias de antemano a todos.
Un saludo

Remplazo en el código esto:

```
Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonText)

i = 3
ws.Cells(2, 1) = "id"
ws.Cells(2, 2) = "Name"
ws.Cells(2, 3) = "Username"
ws.Cells(2, 4) = "Email"
ws.Cells(2, 5) = "Street Address"
ws.Cells(2, 6) = "Suite"
ws.Cells(2, 7) = "City"
ws.Cells(2, 8) = "Zipcode"
ws.Cells(2, 9) = "Phone"
ws.Cells(2, 10) = "Website"
ws.Cells(2, 11) = "Company"

For Each item In jsonObject("data")
    ws.Cells(i, 1) = item("id")
    ws.Cells(i, 2) = item("name")
    ws.Cells(i, 3) = item("username")
    ws.Cells(i, 4) = item("email")
    ws.Cells(i, 5) = item("address")("street")
    ws.Cells(i, 6) = item("address")("suite")
    ws.Cells(i, 7) = item("address")("city")
    ws.Cells(i, 8) = item("address")("zipcode")
    ws.Cells(i, 9) = item("phone")
    ws.Cells(i, 10) = item("website")
    ws.Cells(i, 11) = item("company")("name")
    i = i + 1
```

Por esto:

```
Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonText)

i = 3
ws.Cells(2, 1) = "IdViaEntrada"
ws.Cells(2, 2) = "IdOrigenMetadatoPrioridades"
ws.Cells(2, 3) = "PatronBusquedaFicheroAsociado"
ws.Cells(2, 4) = "PatronReemplazoFicheroAsociado"
ws.Cells(2, 5) = "PatronBusquedaFicheroAlbaran"
ws.Cells(2, 6) = "PatronReemplazoFicheroAlbaran"
ws.Cells(2, 7) = "CopiarFicheroAsociado"
ws.Cells(2, 8) = "SinFicheroAsociadoKO"
ws.Cells(2, 9) = "CopiarFichero"
ws.Cells(2, 10) = "ExtensionesValidas"
ws.Cells(2, 11) = "ExtensionesExcluidasBusqueda"
ws.Cells(2, 12) = "LecturaMultiBidi"
ws.Cells(2, 13) = "LecturaBidi"
ws.Cells(2, 14) = "DescartarKO"
ws.Cells(2, 15) = "RetirarPrimera"
ws.Cells(2, 16) = "RetirarEjemplarII"
ws.Cells(2, 17) = "RetirarBlancas"
ws.Cells(2, 18) = "PorcentajeOcupacion"
ws.Cells(2, 19) = "Estrategias"
ws.Cells(2, 20) = "IdTipoMetadato"
ws.Cells(2, 21) = "NombreMetadato"
ws.Cells(2, 22) = "LoteDesde"
ws.Cells(2, 23) = "LoteHasta"
ws.Cells(2, 24) = "FicherosPorLote"
ws.Cells(2, 25) = "NombreProveedor"
ws.Cells(2, 26) = "IdTipoMetadato"
ws.Cells(2, 27) = "NombreMetadato"
ws.Cells(2, 28) = "ConfiguracionLecturaBidis"
ws.Cells(2, 29) = "ConfiguracionViaEntradaPaginacion"


For Each item In jsonObject("data")
ws.Cells(i, 1) = item("IdViaEntrada")
ws.Cells(i, 2) = item("IdOrigenMetadatoPrioridades")
ws.Cells(i, 3) = item("PatronBusquedaFicheroAsociado")
ws.Cells(i, 4) = item("PatronReemplazoFicheroAsociado")
ws.Cells(i, 5) = item("PatronBusquedaFicheroAlbaran")
ws.Cells(i, 6) = item("PatronReemplazoFicheroAlbaran")
ws.Cells(i, 7) = item("CopiarFicheroAsociado")
ws.Cells(i, 8) = item("SinFicheroAsociadoKO")
ws.Cells(i, 9) = item("CopiarFichero")
ws.Cells(i, 10) = item("ExtensionesValidas")
ws.Cells(i, 11) = item("ExtensionesExcluidasBusqueda")
ws.Cells(i, 12) = item("LecturaMultiBidi")
ws.Cells(i, 13) = item("LecturaBidi")
ws.Cells(i, 14) = item("DescartarKO")
ws.Cells(i, 15) = item("RetirarPrimera")
ws.Cells(i, 16) = item("RetirarEjemplarII")
ws.Cells(i, 17) = item("RetirarBlancas")
ws.Cells(i, 18) = item("PorcentajeOcupacion")
ws.Cells(i, 19) = item("Estrategias")
ws.Cells(i, 20) = item("ConfiguracionXMLs")("IdTipoMetadato")
ws.Cells(i, 21) = item("ConfiguracionXMLs")("NombreMetadato")
ws.Cells(i, 22) = item("ConfiguracionLoteado")("LoteDesde")
ws.Cells(i, 23) = item("ConfiguracionLoteado")("LoteHasta")
ws.Cells(i, 24) = item("ConfiguracionLoteado")("FicherosPorLote")
ws.Cells(i, 25) = item("ConfiguracionLoteado")("NombreProveedor")
ws.Cells(i, 26) = item("ConfiguracionNombre")("IdTipoMetadato")
ws.Cells(i, 27) = item("ConfiguracionNombre")("NombreMetadato")
ws.Cells(i, 28) = item("ConfiguracionLecturaBidis")
ws.Cells(i, 29) = item("ConfiguracionViaEntradaPaginacion")
    i = i + 1
```

El Json a utilizar es:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "IdViaEntrada": 2,
            "IdOrigenMetadatoPrioridades": [
                1,
                3
            ],
            "PatronBusquedaFicheroAsociado": "NombreFichero.xml",
            "PatronReemplazoFicheroAsociado": "NombreFichero",
            "PatronBusquedaFicheroAlbaran": "Albaran.txt",
            "PatronReemplazoFicheroAlbaran": "",
            "CopiarFicheroAsociado": false,
            "SinFicheroAsociadoKO": true,
            "CopiarFichero": false,
            "ExtensionesValidas": [
                8,
                2,
                3,
                4,
                37,
                5,
                6,
                10,
                11,
                12,
                7,
                15,
                16
            ],
            "ExtensionesExcluidasBusqueda": [
                25,
                24,
                27,
                36,
                31
            ],
            "LecturaMultiBidi": false,
            "LecturaBidi": false,
            "DescartarKO": false,
            "RetirarPrimera": false,
            "RetirarEjemplarII": false,
            "RetirarBlancas": false,
            "PorcentajeOcupacion": 99.5,
            "Estrategias": [
                0,
                1
            ],
            "ConfiguracionXMLs": [
                {
                    "IdTipoMetadato": 24,
                    "NombreMetadato": "SUCURSAL",
                    "XPath": "//*[@Name='Oficina' or @Name='OFICINA' or @Name='COD_OFICINA']/@Value",
                    "VolcarDato": true,
                    "TiposDocumentalesValidos": [
                        "I2",
                        "LT"
                    ],
                    "TypeValue": "System.Int32",
                    "FormatoInput": "",
                    "FormatoOutput": "0000"
                },
                {
                    "IdTipoMetadato": 45,
                    "NombreMetadato": "DIGITALIZADOR",
                    "XPath": "//*[@Name='Digitalizador' or @Name='DIGITALIZADOR']/@Value",
                    "VolcarDato": true,
                    "TiposDocumentalesValidos": [
                        "I2",
                        "LT"
                    ],
                    "TypeValue": "System.String",
                    "FormatoInput": "",
                    "FormatoOutput": ""
                },
                {
                    "IdTipoMetadato": 61,
                    "NombreMetadato": "TIPO_DOC",
                    "XPath": "//*[@Name='Tipo Documento' or @Name='TIPO DOCUMENTO']/@Value",
                    "VolcarDato": true,
                    "TiposDocumentalesValidos": [
                        "I2",
                        "LT"
                    ],
                    "TypeValue": "System.String",
                    "FormatoInput": "",
                    "FormatoOutput": ""
                },
                {
                    "IdTipoMetadato": 2,
                    "NombreMetadato": "TIPO_PERSONA",
                    "XPath": "//*[@Name='Tipo Cliente' or @Name='TIPO CLIENTE']/@Value",
                    "VolcarDato": false,
                    "TiposDocumentalesValidos": [
                        "I2",
                        "LT"
                    ],
                    "TypeValue": "System.String",
                    "FormatoInput": "",
                    "FormatoOutput": ""
                },
                {
                    "IdTipoMetadato": 1,
                    "NombreMetadato": "NUM_PERSONA",
                    "XPath": "//*[@Name='Codigo Cliente' or @Name='CODIGO CLIENTE']/@Value",
                    "VolcarDato": false,
                    "TiposDocumentalesValidos": [
                        "I2",
                        "LT"
                    ],
                    "TypeValue": "System.Int32",
                    "FormatoInput": "",
                    "FormatoOutput": ""
                },
                {
                    "IdTipoMetadato": 116,
                    "NombreMetadato": "OrigenSobre",
                    "XPath": "//Batch/@BatchClassName",
                    "VolcarDato": true,
                    "TiposDocumentalesValidos": [
                        "I2",
                        "LT"
                    ],
                    "TypeValue": "System.String",
                    "FormatoInput": "",
                    "FormatoOutput": ""
                }
            ],
            "ConfiguracionLoteado": {
                "LoteDesde": 1,
                "LoteHasta": 200000,
                "FicherosPorLote": 50,
                "NombreProveedor": "SERIMAG"
            },
            "ConfiguracionNombre": {
                "ExpresionesRegulares": [
                    {
                        "IdExpresionRegular": 1,
                        "Expresion": "(?<AltaManual>(?<Banco>0049)_(?<SUCURSAL>[\\d]{4})_[\\w]{3}_(?<TIPO_DOC>[\\w]{2})_(?<TIPO_PERSONA>[FJ]{1})_(?<NUM_PERSONA>[\\d]{1,9})_[\\d]*)"
                    }
                ],
                "ConfiguracionMetadatos": [
                    {
                        "IdExpresionRegular": 1,
                        "IdTipoMetadato": 24,
                        "NombreMetadato": "SUCURSAL",
                        "TypeValue": "System.Int32",
                        "FormatoInput": "",
                        "FormatoOutput": "0000"
                    },
                    {
                        "IdExpresionRegular": 1,
                        "IdTipoMetadato": 61,
                        "NombreMetadato": "TIPO_DOC",
                        "TypeValue": "System.String",
                        "FormatoInput": "",
                        "FormatoOutput": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "IdExpresionRegular": 1,
                        "IdTipoMetadato": 2,
                        "NombreMetadato": "TIPO_PERSONA",
                        "TypeValue": "System.String",
                        "FormatoInput": "",
                        "FormatoOutput": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "IdExpresionRegular": 1,
                        "IdTipoMetadato": 1,
                        "NombreMetadato": "NUM_PERSONA",
                        "TypeValue": "System.Int32",
                        "FormatoInput": "",
                        "FormatoOutput": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            "ConfiguracionLecturaBidis": null,
            "ConfiguracionViaEntradaPaginacion": null
        }
    ]
}
```

> Entiendo que es un objeto de clase que alguien habrá programado.
> Tendrías que mirar el codigo original y ver qué hace item. ¿Lo has
> ejecutado con F8? ¿Has visto si el resto de la matriz se procesa bien?
> – Elier Sánchez E-Infantes

Lo acabo de comprobar entero, se para y no me extrae los datos en estos:

```
ws.Cells(i, 2) = item("IdOrigenMetadatoPrioridades")
ws.Cells(i, 10) = item("ExtensionesValidas")
ws.Cells(i, 11) = item("ExtensionesExcluidasBusqueda")
ws.Cells(i, 19) = item("Estrategias")
ws.Cells(i, 20) = item("ConfiguracionXMLs")("IdTipoMetadato")
ws.Cells(i, 21) = item("ConfiguracionXMLs")("NombreMetadato")
ws.Cells(i, 22) = item("ConfiguracionLoteado")("LoteDesde")
ws.Cells(i, 23) = item("ConfiguracionLoteado")("LoteHasta")
ws.Cells(i, 24) = item("ConfiguracionLoteado")("FicherosPorLote")
ws.Cells(i, 25) = item("ConfiguracionLoteado")("NombreProveedor")
ws.Cells(i, 26) = item("ConfiguracionNombre")("IdTipoMetadato")
ws.Cells(i, 27) = item("ConfiguracionNombre")("NombreMetadato")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He de decir que no soy ninguna experta, intento apañarmelas y hacer mi trabajo un poco mas fácil a la vez que aprendo (Quizás lo que intento hacer no es viable).

Comment: Entiendo que es un objeto de clase que alguien habrá programado. Tendrías que mirar el codigo original y ver qué hace `item`. ¿Lo has ejecutado con F8? ¿Has visto si el resto de la matriz se procesa bien?

Comment: He añadido lo que me has comentado. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El caso es que un JSON no se recorre como un array o un diccionario, tu JSON tiene un sólo item en Data, dentro de Data tienes todo lo que te devuelve, lo que no te devuelve son listados dentro de tu JSON y deben recorrerse cada uno por separado en algo así:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim JSON As Object: Set JSON = ParseJson(TextoJSON)
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim prioridades As Variant
    For Each item In JSON("data")
        For Each prioridades In item("ConfiguracionXMLs")
            Debug.Print prioridades("IdTipoMetadato")
        Next prioridades
    Next item

End Sub
```

De este modo logras sacar todos los IdTipoMetadato almacenados dentro:

[image: Ejemplo]

Fijate en la ventana que dice `Inmediato`, se han mostrado todos los Id porque ya había ejecutado la macro completa.

Debajo, en la ventana `Locales`, puedes ver que contiene el objeto `Item` y si miras más abajo, el objeto que yo he llamado `prioridades` contiene todas tus id porque le he hecho recorrer el item `ConfiguracionXMLs`.

Para poder ver lo que te va a escribir directamente o no, puedes sencillamente importar el JSON a un excel en Datos-Importar desde archivo-archivo JSON. (Guarda tu JSON en un txt).

[image: JSON]

Todo lo que ponga `[List]` en value, vas a tener que recorrerlo a parte como he hecho yo con `ConfiguracionXMLs`.

Espero que esto te ayude a poder acabar tu trabajo.

Comment: Wooooow, mil gracias Damian! Voy a intentar aplicarlo, entiendo todo, pero creo que se me escapan algunas cosas (por mi falta de conocimiento) para unificar todo el trabajo.

Comment: @SandraGonzalez todo lo que en tu JSON no te de un valor, si no varios, debes recorrerlo como recorrers el JSON exterior. Creo que ese sería el resumen.